# Image classification and machine learning (not deep learning) algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Do you know any algorithms and methods that may be successful in image classification? I've read about some combined method using SVM and deep learning, however, I would like to know whether is it possible also to utilize any advantages from approaches other than deep learning.

Comment: What about Decision trees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Support Vector Machines

Support vector machines are supervised learning models with associated learning algorithms that analyze data used for classification and regression analysis. Please note that the SVM is a machine learning algorithm and not deep learning. It can be used for image classification.

**Advantages:**

1. It  provides a good generalization  capability.
2. Reduction in computational complexity.
3. It gains flexibility in the choice of the form of the threshold.

[image]

---

### Decision trees

Decision trees have influenced a wide area of machine learning, covering both classification and regression.

A decision tree is drawn upside down with its root at the top. The end of the branch that doesn’t split anymore is the decision/leaf, the classification step.

**Advantages:**

1. 1.Can handle non parametric training data.
2. Does not require extensive design and training.
3. Simple and computational efficiency is good.

[image]

It can be seen that the decision tree above may be utilized for image classification.